# How to make multiple Fancyapps Carousel Thumbnails on same page?

Tags: carousel, fancybox, thumbnails

How do I create multiple carousel thumbnails on the same page using Fancyapps Carousel Thumbnails?

I see examples below but I am unable to add a second set of carousel thumbnails on same page.  When I try to add a second carousel/thumbnails with a different ID, it does not show up.

Source:
https://fancyapps.com/carousel/plugins/thumbs/

Example provided by Fancyapps:
https://jsfiddle.net/mehfxnd9/

does it have to do something with this code?

```
getElementById("myCarousel")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use different values for `id` attribute, for example, `<div id="myCarousel1" ...`, `<div id="myCarousel2" ...` and then use selector that returns your elements, like `getElementById("myCarousel1")`, `getElementById("myCarousel2")`, etc

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before I posted the question and it didn't work. Tried it again now. Still nothing.  You can try it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes, try in the jsfiddle, it works.

Comment: Just tried it again.  Not working.  Can you fork off the jsfiddle to show please?

Comment: But why don't you show your code?

Comment: Here is the forked jsfiddle with two carousels (used the original jsfiddle from fancyapps maker).  You can see the second carousel is not showing up. 
   https://jsfiddle.net/zcr3bmj0/

Comment: Simply fix JS errors - https://jsfiddle.net/3of5w21p/

Comment: Thanks .I marked it as correct answer.  

Quick question: is it possible to consolidate these two scripts into one?  

Trying to save space.  

    `<script>
      const container1 = document.getElementById("myCarousel1");
      const options1 = { Dots: false };

      new Carousel(container1, options1, { Thumbs });
    </script>
    <script>
      const container2 = document.getElementById("myCarousel2");
      const options2 = { Dots: false };

      new Carousel(container2, options2, { Thumbs });
    </script>`

Comment: Janis, one more question: 
Any idea why my html text editor is giving a syntax error when `{Thumbs}` is present in this line `new Carousel(container1, options1, { Thumbs })`  

That script is in a php include file.

Comment: 1) Yes, of course. 2) I do not know, it depends on your text editor, it's plugins and settings. That line is a valid ES6 code.

Comment: thx. can you show how to consolidate the code in the comments please?

Comment: If you ask me to delete `</script><script>`, then here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/2c5e9Lyb/

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't sure if it can be consolidated more.